# Integration testing in .net with nhibernate

Tags: c#, .net, testing, integration-testing

I've been doing some honest-to-God-TDD for my latest project, and am loving it, having previously done unit testing but not serious TDD I'm finding it helpful.

Some background on my project:

- ASP.Net Front End-
- NHibernate for database interaction with SQL Server 2008 express-
- C# 4.0 DLL's for DOmain Logic and Unit Tests which are done in NUnit and ran through resharper.
- Teamcity CI server running a NAnt build script.

I'm in a sort of 'alpha' release now, and am finding all the bugs are integration bugs, mainly as my integration testing has been manual use of the site, and some minor automated stuff (which I've stopped running). This is pretty poor given how strictly I've nurtured my test suite and I want to rectify it.

My question is, what is the best way to do integration tests, or is there any articles I can read. I understand that testing the UI is going to be a pain in ASP.NET Webforms (will move to a more testable framework in future, but one step at a time). But I want to make sure my interactions with hibernate are tested correctly.

So I need some tips on integration testing in relation to

- Nhibernate (caching, sessions etc)-
- Test data, I've found 'NDBUnit' is that what i should be looking at using to get my data in a good state? Is that compatible with NHibernate?
- Should I swap the database out for SQLite or something? Or just setup another SQL server DB which holds test data only?
- How can I make these tests maintainable? I had a few integration tests but they caused me hassles and found myself avoiding them. I think this was mainly due to me not setting a consistent state each time.

Just some general advice too would be great, I've read TDD by example by Kent Beck and The Art of Unit Testing by Roy Osherove and they were great for unit testing /tdd but I would love to read a little more about integration tests and strategies for writing them (what you should test etc) ---

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the Database part:
 - You may use it directly along the lines of this article: [Unit testing with built-in NHibernate support](http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2009/09/10/unit-testing-with-built-in-nhibernate-support.aspx).
 - Using SQLite to speed up the tests can also be very useful. Only that in this case you should be aware that you're not really targeting the real production configuration anymore.
 - SQLite does not support all features that SQL Server does. [This article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/28/nhibernate-unit-testing.aspx) shows a code sample for the necessary test setup to switch to SQLite - it's quite easy and straightforward.
 - NDbUnit as a mechanism to have the test data prepared is also a good choice - as long as you don't expect to have frequent schema changes on your Db (in this case it becomes quite a lot of work to maintain all the related xml files...).
Concerning the ASP.NET part:
 - You may find a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) helpful for UI-driven tests.

HTH!
Thomas

Comment: If you using VS2010(ultimate/premium) - you can also use Coded UI for you UI tests.

Comment: @Ahmad. Doesn't this work only with TFS? So you need the entire TFS infrastructure in place for this?

Comment: nope - we had a demo of it last Friday. The presenter used his laptop and gave a start to finish demo so I'm pretty sure about this. The other aspect is that the coded ui tests can be automated using nant, msbuild etc similar to you normal unit tests. At the end of the day, its just test code...

Comment: @Ahmad. Thanks for the info - was not sure about that. Regarding the automation aspect: Selenium is a framework that you just call from your normal test methods - so no automation trouble here also...

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I've used Selenium on a JSP project before, was a bit of a pain to maintain but I guess that maintenance cost would save me time on manually testing the UI each time so I might take a look at it. Thanks for hte advice on NDBUnit, perhaps instead of sqlite I could just create a test DB in SQL server to start with - will make the transition smoother, then I can look at changing if the tests run too slow.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but this is what I've been doing for a while.

I am writing REST API's, which are to be consumed by our mobile apps. The mobile apps are also written in C#, so it makes sense for me to write an API wrapper (SDK).

When integration testing, I set up test cases that tests all endpoints of the API, **using the SDK**. When running the tests, the API is running on my local IIS, in development mode. Everytime the server is started, my dev database is wiped, recreated, and **seeded with data for all tables**, giving me a somewhat realistic scenario. I also don't have to worry about testing updates/deletes, because all it takes is a rebuild of the server project, and NHibernate will drop, create and seed my database. This could be changed to every request if desired.

When testing my repositories, it's important for me to know if my queries are translateable by NHibernate, so all my repository tests are using LocalDB, which is recreated *for every single test case*. That means every test case can set up the required seed data for the query tests to succeed.

Another thing, when seeding your database with realistic data, you are also getting your foreign-key setups tested for free. Also, the seeder is using your domain classes, so it look's good, too!

An example of a seeder:

```
public void Seed(ISession s) 
{
  using(var tx = s.BeginTransaction() 
  {
    var account1 = new Account { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Smith" };
    var account2 = new Account { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    account1.AddFriend(account2); // manipulates a friends collection
    s.Save(account1);
  }
}
```

You should call the seeder when creating your session factory.

**Important:** setting this up is done with an IoC container.

Answer (score -3):

**The short answer is: don't do integration tests.**

We have the following setup:

- Our unit tests test as little as possible. We only test one function of the business code (not directly a method, but more a logical piece of functionality);
- Write a unit test for every function of your business code;
- Write a unit test for interaction between different functions of your business code;
- Make sure these tests cover everything.

This will give you a set of unit tests that cover everything.

We do have integration tests, but these are written up in Word documents and are often just the original specs. A QA person runs these when the code is delivered and most of the times it just works, because we've already tested every little piece.

On InfoQ, there is a terrific presentation which explains this way of working very well: [Integration Tests Are a Scam](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam).

One thing about testing NHibernate. We have applied the [repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c). What this does is that our NHibernate queries become very very simple, like:

```
public class NhRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return GetSession().Get<T>(id);
    }
}

public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{
    IEnumerable<User> GetActiveUsers();
}

public class UserRepository : NhRepository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<User> GetActiveUsers()
    {
        return
            from user in GetSession().Users
            where user.IsActive
            return user;
    }
}
```

This in combination with the [Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/) IoC container provides our data access. The thing with this setup is that:

1. The queries are incredibly simple (98% of them anyway) and we don't test them thoroughly. That may sound strange, but we tend to test these more using peer review than any other mechanism;
2. These repositories can be easily mocked. This means that for the above repository, we have a mock that does something like this:

   ```
   var repositoryMock = mocks.StrictMock<IUserRepository>();

   var activeUsers = new List<User>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       var user = UserMocks.CreateUser();
       user.IsActive = true;
       activeUsers.Add(user);
   }

   Expect.Call(repositoryMock.GetActiveUsers()).Return(activeUsers);
   ```

   The actual code is a lot more concise, but you get the idea.

Comment: You mean the InfoQ presentation?

Comment: Thanks Pieter, that setup is pretty much exactly what I'm using, Windsor, Rhino Mocks, NHibernate with Repository pattern, great coverage of the domain only, mocks of the database. I'm a one man team on this project so I don't have any QA department to do manual testing, so I'm pretty much manual testing now. What do you do to debug integration issues? For instance, nhibernate uses blank constructors + properties, and creates objects that way, or do you unit test those and try to replicate exactly what nhibernate does in your unit test code?

Comment: I fake what NHibernate does. I've created a set of entity mock factories which build fake mocks for me. I create two types of mocks: a very simple one what is not valid with my domain constraints, and valid ones. The invalid ones I use to build a valid entity because I need to set all the properties. That way, I ensure I don't build an entire database in memory when I need a single entity. When I need collections in an entity property, I build them on the fly. That way I load the entities like NHibernate would.

Comment: Seriously? Do not write integration tests? I would like to see a project, properly tested just with Unit Tests. The question than becomes, how much do you trust your mocks?